# User Conflict- Mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, user-account

My `home` folder is called `admin`. However, I am signed in as `John` and there is no `admin` user. `John` is an administrative user.
Shouldn't the home folder show the signed-in user name?

This may or may not be something I caused

- had another MacBook Pro crash, and this issue has arisen on replacement MacBook Pro and download from JustCloud
- which, among other things, has UPDATED every file to the download date!- among other download issues.

I was having duplicate `Desktop` issues, including a user home folder `Harry` (also not showing in the `Users` preference pane.

Re-installed Mavericks, and this seemed to fix the home directory issue and that user issue. No more `Harry` and no more duplicate desktops.

But, now "admin" appears seemingly out of nowhere.

Comment: How may users have you had Hohn, henry and admin - any more on this machine. Also when you got the new machine did you install OSX from scratch or did it have users?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create new user with admin privileges and delete all others.

That should get rid off the unwanted.

You can try rebuilding your user account as described [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57437548-263/how-to-rebuild-a-user-account-in-os-x/).

Comment: Possibly need to domthis several times - what the issue is probably that you have several uids not matching what you expect so add admin users until you get a good one then delete the rest.